# Setting defaults after a value is chosen

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-collector, domains

I am developing a way for field workers to use arc collector on tablets.

I ran into a problem during development. Here is the way its set up: three workers create points in arc collector on three separate tablets, and in the attribute table for these points is a field to input their initials to show who created the point. I have created a drop-down of their initials to make it easier, but they are saying it would save time to have the default set to their initials instead of having to use the drop down for every point. I do not know how to set a default for three different initials for three different tablets. Is it possible to set a default in a domain after a value is chosen instead of before, even if its just in ArcMap? Is there another way of getting around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a much easier work-around: [enable editor tracking](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/publish-services/windows/editor-tracking-for-feature-services.htm).